# Inform other users that my table SQL has changed in real time in Javascript - SQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, vue.js, watch

In my app, a lot of users can add element in a table of my database postgreSQL.
If a user had a new element in my table, I want to inform the other users using the app simultanely that the content of the table changed - that the user add a new element in the table.

A solution: I could get the content of my table every X secondes (or minutes) and compare the new result with the previous result, but I think it will be too much consuming of request.

There is a solution to send like a flag to the front every time that the content of a table change in postgresql ? Or something similar to solve my problem ?

My front: Vue JS
My back: Node JS
My database: PostgreSQL

Comment: server-sent events - or for PWA's ... push notification

Comment: what you need is web sockets. 
basically you create a "permanent" connexion with your server, so the server can push messages to your frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @jeremycastelli for your help ! I used socket.io tp solve my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

postgreSQL has a [LISTEN / NOTIFY feature](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-notify.html). You can create a rule that sends NOTIFY whenever a table changes. Then your connections that LISTENed will receive those asynchronous events.

You can, alternatively, adopt some sort of message-queuing system. Then you can add to your code that inserts/updates your table to also send a message into your queuing system. Then, your server code can subscribe to those messages and send them along to your client code.

redis is good for this queuing work.  So is RabbitMQ.

To push notifications from the server side of your web app to your clients you'll need socket.io, or Websockets, or for your clients to poll your web servers.